# как управлять MODBUS?

Tags: c#, modbus

Есть прибор. Связь с ним идет по MODBUS. как можно связаться с ним?  написал код что б посылать что команду в com port, но ничего не приходит обратно.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace FTnew
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string name,speed,text,readT=null;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string[] port = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(port);

         name= comboBox1.Text = comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();

          speed=  comboBox2.Text = comboBox2.Items[6].ToString();




        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            Thread kol = new Thread(check);
            kol.Start();
        }



        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = name;
                serialPort1.Open();
                serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(speed);


            }
            text = richTextBox1.Text;
        serialPort1.WriteLine(text);

        }


        void check()
        {

            while (true) { 
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {


                    readT = serialPort1.ReadExisting().ToString();


                    foreach (var tt in readT)
                    {

                        if (tt != null) MessageBox.Show("lol");
                        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => richTextBox2.Text += tt));

                    }
                }



            }
        }
    }
}
```